# python imaging library save function

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have just done some image processing using the python image library (PIL) and I can't get the save function to work. the whole code works fine but it just wont save the resulting image. The code is below:

```
im=Image.new("rgb",(200,10),"#ddd")
draw=Image.draw.draw(im)
draw.text((10,10),"run away",fill="red")
im.save("g.jpeg")
```

Saving gives an error as unknown extension and even removing the dot doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.jpg`:

```
im.save("g.jpg")
```

The image library determines what encoder to use by the extension, but in certain versions of PIL the JPEG encoder do not register the `.jpeg` extension, only `.jpg`.

Another possibility is that your PIL installation doesn't support JPEG *at all*; try saving the image as a PNG, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
draw=Image.draw.draw(im)
```

with

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```

and make sure the height of the new image is tall enough to accomodate the text.

```
import Image
import ImageDraw

im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 30), "#ddd")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.text((10, 10), "run away", fill="red")
im.save("g.jpeg")
```

yields

[image]

Comment: This might be library specific (see Martijn's answer).

Answer (score 0):

please save with .jpg extention eg:

```
im.save("g.jpg")
```