# How can I get the size of the image from an ImageDraw.Draw object?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have a Pillow (PIL) image called `img`. I create a drawing object with `drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)`. Now I pass `drawer` to a function. How can that function see the size of the image? (If I just pass the image, I can get the size easily with `img.size`)

Comment: Note that an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486077/how-to-get-image-from-imagedraw-in-pil) would suffice as well, but the current answer to that question does not actually answer the question in the title.

Comment: Using the `dir` function, I was able to find that `drawer` has an `im` property, but the `im` property is an ImagingCore object, and I don't know how to turn that into a normal image in order to get the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR `drawer.im.size`

The `ImageDraw.Draw` object has a property called `im` that can be used to get a `ImagingCore` object (Note that this is not the usual `Image` object) which has a `size` property. Testing it, the size property seems to match that of the original image, so that is what I will use for now.